# Used memory reported by Valgrind is HUGE

Tags: c, valgrind

I´m writing a version of strcat that can allocate memory accordingly to the size of the input string. For this I´m using realloc.

I have been doing some tests with lots of strings. In some test concatenating 9,193 strings, results in a string with a length of 64,344. I checked it with valgrind but I found the results a bit disturbing...

```
HEAP SUMMARY
    in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
    total heap usage: 9193 allocs, 9,193 frees, 338,017,768 bytes allocated

All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are posible

For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with -v
ERROR SUMMARY: 0 Errors form 0 contexts (suppresed: 0 from 0)
```

The program runs well and acceptably fast in my opinion, but I'm worried with the 338,017,768 bytes allocated message, I think it´s too much for a simple string concatenation.

What does "bytes allocated" exactly mean??

Thanks.

Comment: It means that on average you allocated about 36 KiB per call to `malloc()` et al. Since you know that some of the allocations were in the region of 64 KiB, this doesn't look too bad.  And you freed it all, so you probably don't have anything to worry about.  As already indicated (by some of the answers), it doesn't automatically mean your program grew to 300+ MiB.

Answer (score 3):

It's the amount of memory that would have been allocated by your program if it had never called `free`.  It has nothing to do with peak memory usage.

You could get the same result by doing this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 338017768; ++i) {
    free(malloc(1));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So.. it means that to create a (more or less) 65 kB string, the program used 338 MB in its execution???

Answer (score 1):

That can have two reasons:

a) depending on how you concatenate strings the standard procedure is:

```
allocate enough memory to hold the concatenation
copy both strings into it
deallocate memory occupied by the initial strings
```

If you do this with a lot of strings then it will allocate appx `n^2` memory where `n` is the length of your result string.

b) Not all memory that gets allocated actually gets used, buffers are often allocated larger then they need to be. And not all memory that is allocated actually ever gets physical RAM attached to it. This is the standard way of handling virtual memory.

If I `malloc` 1 GB of memory, my process will not actually consume that much physical RAM until I start using it. It will be provided in chunks of system pages in an on-demand fashion.